# Azure IoT Central - Multiple Topic Paths into one device

Tags: azure, path, mqtt, azure-iot-central

I have a physical hardware device that I have zero access to the code.  The device is preconfigured to send data via MQTT.  I've managed to connect the device to IoT Central however the device sends data to a variety of different topics which I think is causing the IoT Central to disconnect the device.

The topics are as follows:

- MqttTopicBase/clientinfo
- MqttTopicBase/clientstatus
- MqttTopicBase/port/n/status
- MqttTopicBase/port/n/event
- MqttTopicBase/port/n/pdi
- MqttTopicBase/port/n/pdo

Where n is between 1-8 and I somehow need to capture this number.

Is it possible to configure IoT Central to access data from multiple different topics (and ideally capture the n value from the topics), and if not are there any suggested workarounds or intermediary steps in order to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Central is not a full-featured MQTT broker. Please check how to [Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly) - it applies to IoT Central as well.

To workaround you can also use [Azure IoT Central Device Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-build-iotc-device-bridge) , [IoT Plug and Play bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/concepts-iot-pnp-bridge) or [Azure IoT Edge MQTT broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11).